# How to assign a unique ID to a webservice instance

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jax-rpc

I'd like to assign an unique identifier to a soap request as soon as it arrives at my (GlassFish 2) server. I suppose I use a handler for this.

But where can I store such an ID? I need it to relate log-lines from multiple classes. For this I need some sort of context-object. Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to open a session with the client (i.e. stateful SOAP instead of stateless). [This blog post](http://tssblog.blogs.techtarget.com/2007/04/27/stateful-soap-and-beans/) contains some answers.

And you have to pass the session ID to the client. Otherwise, you can't tell if a second request is coming from the same client or not.

Comment: That's a solution I hadn't thought of. But I don't need to relate multiple requests, but just log-lines. I'll update my question accordingly.